# Electric current during meditation

Tags: energy

There have been some similar questions, but still not quite the same.
Whenever I want to (not only during meditation), I can generate an electric current.
I sort of have to open up at the third eye, do something in my gut area, and then can direct it, or hold it a short time.
I also seem to be able to pass it on to others.

What can or should I do with this? Or should I just ignore it? But it feels right, to use and play with it.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1):

Don't play with yourself during meditation.  You're wasting your time and I hear that you can go blind if you do it too often.

Seriously, though, what you are experiencing is just your own internal energy.  Call it qi, call in prajna, call it whatever.  It's important, but if you get obsessive about it, it's going to undermine your meditation practice.  Buddhist meditation is about liberation.  It has nothing to do with working with subtle bodies, astral projection, or healing your Aunt Milly's lumbago from across three continents.

It's important that you don't try to raise this energy.  Any forced, willful manipulation of it is completely artificial and potentially nothing more than self delusion.  Removed from the hindrances, secluded, putting aside grief and covetousness for the world (including feeling that energy), it will rise all of it's own accord.  When it does, just let it do what it's going to do.  It will probably start to feel different.  It may disappear entirely.  You might also start to feel uncomfortable tension in your body; most likely you'll start to get antsy...whatever happens just sit in it.  Don't move.  Eventually, you will pass through a barrier.   On the other side of it, all of that will dissolve and you will be left in a place that feels spacious and open.  That's where you ought to be aiming for.

Don't expect this to happen all at once.  It will most likely take several years of practice.  You might get glimpses of it here and there, but let me assure you that when you finally arrive there, the experience will be unmistakable.  Then your practice actually begins!

For now, put everything else aside.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. So this is maybe what the vrittis in yoga are describing? I can completely neglect it during meditation, since it comes and goes by my choice. But I thought, I could somehow accelerate with it, whatever I am trying to achieve during meditation.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of [Pīti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti):

- **Weak rapture** only causes piloerection.
- **Short rapture** evocates some thunder "from time to time".
- **Going down rapture** explodes inside the body, like waves.
- **Exalting rapture** "makes the body jump to the sky".
- **Fulfilling rapture** seems to be a huge flood of a mountain stream.

> **Going down rapture** explodes inside the body, like waves.

May also feel like a current or flow running through your body.

As with any meditation experience, this is a product of:

- past accumulated conditioning, and
- conditioning created by meditation.

None of which are in your absolute control.

So thinking along these lines:

> I sort of have to open up at the third eye, do something in my gut area, and then can direct it, or hold it a short time. I also seem to be able to pass it on to others.

as these experiences are not fully controllable.

Dwelling or trying to control these experiences as mentioned:

> What can or should I do with this? Or should I just ignore it? But it feels right, to use and play with it.

also lead to attachment which is counterproductive to the goals of Buddhist meditation.

One can try to develop mastery over the Jhana factors with caution so that this does not lead to attachment and distraction from the goals of meditation.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice. I will put it aside and focus on my meditation